# TCP port not listening on WCF Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, port

I have followed the instructions to create a Windows service to listen on a TCP port shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

However, when testing the service installs correctly, runs in the services app and is currently using an administrator's permissions, but there no process listening on the port specified.

Windows Service code:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using WcfServiceLibrary2010;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1: ServiceBase
    {
        internal static ServiceHost myServiceHost = null; 

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
            }
            myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
            myServiceHost.Open();
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (myServiceHost != null)
            {
                myServiceHost.Close();
                myServiceHost = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To try and identify whats going on I have created a console application project, referencing the same custom WCF library as before (*WcfServiceLibrary2010*), running the same code that Windows Service project does:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using WcfServiceLibrary2010;

namespace ConsoleHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
            sh.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("sh has {0} ChannelDispatchers", sh.ChannelDispatchers.Count);

            foreach (var disp in sh.ChannelDispatchers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" - Binding: {0}", disp);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Listening - press enter to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();

            sh.Close();
        }
    }
```

The process of creating a new ServiceHost and opening it is identical between the ConsoleHost and the Windows Service, it seems the ConsoleHost ran successfully, listening on the port specified.

What might be different then when incorporating the Window Service project into my solution that causes the program not to listen on the port? Even when the code used is the same.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: app.config file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary2010.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WcfServiceLibrary2010.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8989/Service1" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: How do you know that it does not listen to the port in case of windows service  and it does listen in case of console host? Can you share the code of Service1 and your configuration files?

Comment: Hi there, the code for Service1 is shown in the first code block, the code for the console host shown in the 2nd. I'll add in the app config now. 
And in order to verify as to whether the port listens I have run the console command "  netstat -an | find "8989"  " and also checked using the Windows TCPView program